# JAI RangeLookup operation missing from registry but works fine in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, gradle, vectorization, geotools, jai

Which dependency am I lacking if:

```
No OperationDescriptor is registered in the current operation registry
```

is returned why trying to use geo tools via JAI to vectorize an image?

```
compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-arcgrid', version: '18.4'
compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-process-raster', version: '18.4'
compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-main', version: '18.4'
```

https://github.com/geoHeil/vectorizePolygons contains the example code.

## edit

when executing the code from IntelliJ everything works just fine.
Only when executing the code from gradle or maven created fat jar the code fails to load some dependencies.

Even when following along here http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app see: https://github.com/geoHeil/vectorizePolygons/blob/master/maven/pom.xml IntelliJ will see a different class path which works just fine. But neither maven or gradle report any problems when creating the fat jar.

Maven fails with a different error:

```
javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpiit.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.arcgrid.spi.AsciiGridsImageReaderSpi not found
```

gradle fails at this line:

```
final RenderedOp asciiCoverage = JAI.create("ImageRead", pbjImageRead, hints);
```

which sort of seems to be related to some image reading in both places.

## edit

[image]

### edit 2

After fixing the maven problem (updating maven-shade-plugin) now also maven reports a missing registration in the `JAI` operation registry.

`RangeLookup` is missing.

Comment: The name of the provider in the Maven error message; `it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpiit.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.arcgrid.spi.AsciiGridsImageReaderSpi` does seem to indicate a missing line feed (between `...TIFFImageReaderSpi` and `it.geosolutions...`) in the merged `META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi` entry.

Comment: When you look at the pom.xml how could this be fixed? See the last edit. I could confirm that your suggestion is correct. Also, I noted that gradle does seem to **not** include any TIFF related file into the `META_INF/services`

Comment: I don't know for sure... It's probably a bug in the `org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer` to not insert the newline. or report the missing one as a problem. But a quick-fix could be to look at all the `ImageReaderSpi` files that will be merged, and make sure they all end with a line feed (the culprit is most likely the one containing the `TIFFImageReader`).

Comment: Indeed. You were correct. Just updated the maven-shade-plugin. Not it is one step ahead of gradle ;) and fails with `llegalArgumentException: RangeLookup: No OperationDescriptor is registered in the current operation registry under this name`